# How do you set the order of libraries in automake?

Tags: c, gcc, autotools, autoconf, automake

How do you set the order of libraries in automake?

In my am file I have something like:

```
myprog_DEPENDENCIES = adhoc-target
myprog_SOURCES = myprog.c
myprog_LDADD = libmine.la
myprog_LDFLAGS = -static -L/home/user/lib -ladhoc
```

Now, when I compile I get this compile line similar too:

```
gcc -static myprog-myprog.o -o myprog -L/home/user/lib -ladhoc ./.libs/libmine.a
```

The problem is that libmine.a depends on libadhoc.a, therefore the compile line should be:

```
gcc -static myprog-myprog.o -o myprog ./.libs/libmine.a -L/home/user/lib -ladhoc
```

How do you set the order of libraries in automake? (Or maybe a work around; how do you repeat all the libraries in the compile line. That's what I do in my custom Makefiles.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Automake manual (mostly [§8.1.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Linking.html) but also [§8.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html)):

> `PROG_LDADD` is inappropriate for
>   passing program-specific linker flags
>   (except for `-l`, `-L`, `-dlopen` and
>   `-dlpreopen`).  So, use the
>   `PROG_LDFLAGS` variable for this
>   purpose.

That implies you can (but actually you should) use `-l` and `-L` in `LDADD`, not in `LDFLAGS`.  In other words your `Makefile.am` should simply read

```
myprog_DEPENDENCIES = adhoc-target
myprog_SOURCES = myprog.c
myprog_LDADD = libmine.la -L/home/user/lib -ladhoc
myprog_LDFLAGS = -static
```

Comment: This solved the nearly-identical problem I was having with libgcrypt.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One idea from the automake book (http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/autobook/autobook_92.html): create a convenience library out of libmine and libadhoc, and link myprog against that.